# Deployment using Eclipse PHP

Tags: php, eclipse-pdt

I have a small PHP project with a MySQL database, that I have been programming on notepad and uploading directly to my remote server using FTP.

Now I have installed ECLIPSE PHP and I would like to know if is there a way to sycronize or deploy my local project on the remote server (without manual copy/paste using FTP), and connect it to the remote MySQL to test it. I cannot find the option.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

when you do it, why not do it right? ;) There are a ton of Plugins for Eclipse, for example you could use SVN ( http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/ ) for releasing and Version controlling or GIT ( http://www.eclipse.org/egit/ ).

If its all about speed (and you work under linux, which I hope you do) why not work directly via SSHFS ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS )

Just some thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this option is in Eclipse by default but you can use a plugin.

From the Eclipse MarketPlace (because they do have an *appstore* too :D), I found [projx-transfer](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/projx-transfer?mpc=true&mpc_state=) that seems to be perfect for you.

Comment: Does any one know of a up to date version of Porj-x? The original creator don't maintin it any more. The source is [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/proj-x) though if any one have the knowledge to use it.

Comment: This could more or less be done with ANT. Have a look over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13298084/1592572)